What is this blight on my apple tree

Can anyone tell me how to deal with this?  I planted this apple tree about 18 months ago.

looks like roots

This is not a blight.  Most if not all apple trees are grafted onto a different root stock to accomplish various goals such as a smaller tree or better growth.
The root stock for this tree has decided to reject the top graft and is growing its own roots or leaves.
I would raise this issue with the grower. The main causes of this are graft incompatibility or physical damage to the top graft which does not seem to be the issue here.
The picture that has been added doesn't show enough detail to determine if the tree has been planted high and these are roots coming from the root stock.  If that is the case then top dressing with soil might be all that is needed.
You do not want to let the root stock start growing leaves. Any stems that grow leaves should be ripped off at the base. If you cut them they will come back.

Thanks for that.  Do I just hope for the best?  The tree was in good health this summer.

@steve added more details - top dressing the growth on the root stock might be all that is necessary
